# Is there a difference between the `Imports` statement in code and the Imported namespaces function?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

As I'm coding through my program, I'm noticing that I have a LOT of `Imports` statements in my code and I noticed that I'm getting a lot of "Messages" saying that the `Imports` statement is not necessary and found it was included in the list of "Imported Namespaces" in Visual Studio 2022.

I wanted to know if there is a performance hit of any kind of it's more beneficial to use the "Imported Namespaces" instead of the `Imports` statement.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in terms of how the code behaves.  An `Imports` statement in the code allows the file to be cleanly ported between projects with different project-level import settings, and it allows for finer-grained control of namespace imports from one file to another (could be an issue if there end up being name collisions between different namespaces, especially if they involve extension methods).

Comment: Import statements have to do with how long the name qualifier is in your code. It should have no effect on performance.

Comment: `Imports` is a typing aid. Instead of going `System.IO.Blah` in code you import `System.IO`. However `Imports` should be not too many. You especially don't want conflicting names in your namespace. That would require you to specify which one you want losing the typing advantage of using `Imports`. These are the two I commonly use, and second only sometimes. `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices`
and `Imports System.IO`. I use API calls and COM a lot.